# gitweb redirect to https

Tags: git, redirect, https, apache2, gitweb

I am an Apache noob and am trying to automatically redirect requests for http://.com/gitweb to https://.com/gitweb

I've set the following to /etc/apache2/conf.d/gitweb

```
Alias /gitweb /usr/share/gitweb
<Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
  Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Redirect gitweb https://<myserver>.com/gitweb
  SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

However I just keep getting the 403 forbidden notice

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /gitweb on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at dndo-gamma Port 80
```

I don't want all directories hosted by this server to redirect; just the request for gitweb.

My /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default is unchanged from its default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl is also unchanged from default ubuntu/apache2 installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually i use `mod_rewrite` for these kind of tasks:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite_log"

    RewriteRule ^/gitweb/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/gitweb/%1 [R]
```

but this is not programming but server-configuration; you might consider asking this question on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)